# Flask sqlite database issues

Tags: jquery, python, sqlite, flask

With JS/jQuery I do the below to GET a JSON string:

```
$(document).on('click',".order_submit", function() {

     prodJSON = JSON.stringify(prodData)
     console.log(prodJSON)

        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: prodJSON
        });

});
```

A console.log of the string gives this:

```
[{"name":"Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt","price":"10.50","quantity":1}]
```

Here is my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def entry_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        # data = data.loads()
        data = data.loads

        print data
        # name = data['name']
        # print name
        # price = data['price']
        # quantity = data['quantity']
        # db = get_db()
        # order = db.execute('insert into orders (name, price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?)',
        #  [data[name], data[price], data[quantity]] )
        # db.commit()
        return render_template('thankyou.html')
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
```

In terminal, the print that i am getting of `data` is this:

```
[{%22name%22:%22Sip%20%27n%27%20Sizzle%20T-Shirt%22,%22price%22:%2210.50%22,%22quantity%22:1}]
```

Trying to access values in the dictionary doesn't work.  Do I need to change something in my JS?  Also, it still is not rendering the thankyou.html template that is returned in the if statement.

Comment: `if request.get_json == 'POST'` will *always* return `False` as you are comparing the method `get_json` with the string `'POST'` - you want `request.method` ... changing that should make the most difference :-)

Comment: @SeanVieira Thanks! I changed it and I am now getting this error: `500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Comment: `data = request.get_json.loads()` should be `data = request.get_json()`

Comment: @SeanVieira i completely updated my question above

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you data is -

```
[{"name":"Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt","price":"10.50","quantity":1}]
```

If that is truly the case you have a list with the single element which is a dictionary.  To access the dictionary, you must first access the element in the list.

```
data[0]['name']
```

Comment: `data[0]['name']` gives me the entire list with all dictionary keys

Comment: Are you running your application in debug mode?  It will give more information and a nice stack trace.

Comment: yea, i've rewritten a bunch of code i'm going to post a new question because i think i have some other issues to worry about before i get into the db stuff.  thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem.  Honestly for what you want to do, you should generate some test cases.  Don't even use the web browser.  Once your tests work, *then* bring in the browser.

Comment: To be honest I've never tested anything and wouldn't even know where to begin.  It's something I would like to learn how to do soon though.